How to register np.float128 as a valid numba type so I can sum an array?
I want to write a numba function that takes the sum of an array of np.float128s.  These have 80 bits of precision on my set up but if it is easier to cast them to real float128s I would be happy with that as well. My goal is to be able to sum an array of np.float128s quickly and without loss of precision, ultimately returning a np.float128 to my python code.
To do this I am trying to copy the model from https://github.com/gmarkall/numba-bfloat16/blob/main/prototype.py.  I am skipping the parts relating to CUDA because I will not be writing CUDA code but I don't know if I need to replace them with something.
So far I have:
import numpy as np
from numba.core.types.scalars import Number
from numba.np import numpy_support

class Float128(Number):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kws):
        super().__init__(name='float128')

float128_type = Float128()
numpy_support.FROM_DTYPE[np.dtype(np.float128)] = float128_type

The next part from the link is:
@intrinsic
def bfloat16_add(typingctx, a, b):
    sig = bfloat16_type(bfloat16_type, bfloat16_type)

    def codegen(context, builder, sig, args):
        i16 = ir.IntType(16)
        function_type = ir.FunctionType(i16, [i16, i16])
        instruction = ("{.reg.b16 one; "
                       "mov.b16 one, 0x3f80U; "
                       "fma.rn.bf16 $0, $1, one, $2;}")
        asm = ir.InlineAsm(function_type, instruction, "=h,h,h")
        return builder.call(asm, args)

    return sig, codegen

What should I replace bfloat16_add with for my float128? I think I need to define addition for numba....?
Edit
I will be doing sums on millions of arrays of length less than 10k. For arrays of float64s, fast numba code is many times faster than np,sum, especially if you use fastmath=True. For example,
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
@nb.njit(cache=True, fastmath=True)
def fast_sum(arr):
    s = 0.0
    for v in arr:
        s += v
    return s


@nb.njit(cache=True)
def numba_sum_nofastmath(arr):
    s = 0.0
    for v in arr:
        s += v
    return s


A = np.random.random(1000)

%timeit fast_sum(A)
404 ns ± 2.03 ns per loop (mean ±    std.dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

%timeit numba_sum_nofastmath(A)
964 ns ± 14.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)


%timeit np.sum(A)
2.86 µs ± 12.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

%timeit A.sum()
1.72 µs ± 34.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each

If I convert the type to np.float128 I get:
A_float128 = A.astype(np.float128)

%timeit np.sum(A_float128)
4.3 µs ± 13.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)


%timeit A_float128.sum()
3.17 µs ± 70 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

but fast_sum(A_float128) fails to run with
NumbaValueError: Unsupported array dtype: float128

I already have numpy.float128s in my code. I would like to be able to use them with numba without having to convert them all to float64s.

I think this misunderstands the original code. BF16 is a native CUDA type added to python (via numba). np.float128 is ill-defined. It can be FP64, in which case the 64 bits of padding is pointless and you just would need a stride trick to ignore the padding. But if it's x87 FP80 as indicated, with 48 bits of padding, then you're straight out of luck. CUDA is not x87, and does not have an FP80 type. Even x86-64 does not like FP80. x86-64 uses SSE for regular FP, and needs to fall back to slow x87 code path (likely emulated in firmware) for FP80

@MSalters my goal is simply to sum the array without casting the floats to 64 bits and losing precision. This is not CUDA code that I am implementing.

Some background: numba works by compiling Python code using LLVM. ir in the example code refers to LLVM's Intermediate Representation. Hence, this question is essentially "how do I write LLVM IR for float128 ?"

Where from do you originally get the float128 values you need to add without loss of precision? How do you get these values into an array you want then to be summed up?

@Claudio They are the result of a series of mathematical calculations.

@Simd : sorry, I was maybe not clear enough in my question. I am not asking how you obtained them as result, but how do they find their way into Python script code array which by default does not support storing them?

@Claudio You can use np.float128() for your constants in python and then do calculations using those types.

On my machine seems there is no actual float128 precision available (max. 16 decimal digits). If it is available on your machine why not using numpy sum() for them? Or provide them as integers and sum these with Python sum() ?

@Claudio I want to use numba to speed up sum. It is much faster unless you have very long arrays.

May you provide a minimal example of working code which compares timings of numpy and numba demonstrating what you speak about with an array size which can then be used to test alternative solutions in case of extending the precision to 80 bits?

... and with an amount of sums you target for accumulated saving of time to turn caring about microseconds a making sense requirement.

@Claudio I added some timings in the comments for a different answer. I can add them to the question in about 16 hours time.  I perform many millions of these sums in my code so speed is very important.

@Simd : yes, I know - you have provided code for timings ... but ... forgot to mention the size of the array, so it can't be reproduced ...

@Claudio it's in the data creation line A = np.random.random(1000)

@Simd : anyway for answers it is better it is part of the question ...

Is it known in which range of values are the np.float128 ones? The minimum and the maximum possible value?

You benchmark with length 1000. Is that your average length?

@nocomment  yes it is

I just tried to give a look to the Numba low level API and this is a pain. The amount of code to write for very very simple things is rather big. When something is wrong, you get an error with a callstack of 270 lines insane to understand (unless you are a Numba core developer). There are open bugs on people using this API and it might change over time btw. The final code will not be portable : it will only works on x86 CPUs and certainly only on Linux (this type is not available on my Windows but is on my Linux). Last but not least, this is only for a 2048 ULP additional precision (small).

What about just calling a C or Cython code from Numba? Honestly, for such a simple operation this is far simpler, certainly as fast, easier to maintain, and more stable over time, not to mention it will be portable. I do not see any downside beside you need an ahead-of-time compilation step (but the benefit is that you not runtime compilation is needed anymore for that).

Oh and note that if you perform a naive sum of 1000 numbers, then the precision is AFAIK about ~30 ULP in average and ~1000 ULP in the worst case (about 10~20 ULP for Numpy). Since FP80 only has an additional precision of 2048 ULP over FP64, it means you may lose all the additional precision during the summation. In my experience, it is most of the time better to use numerically stable algorithms (e.g. Kahan sum reaching an error of few ULP) rather than extended precision (though the later is often simpler). It is not always simple nor possible to use a more numerically stable algorithm though

@JérômeRichard I would be happy to call C or Cython. I can't work out how to get it to work in  Cython either though.

This answer provide a solution to call a C function (doing the actual sum) from Python. As pointed out in the comment, it is far simpler than implementing the required operation in Numba and it is more portable between CPU architectures (as well as possibly more flexible too).
For sake of simplicity, I assume you run on Linux in this question since AFAIK the extended 80-bit floating point type known as np.float128 is not available on Windows systems (IDK on MacOS). Note that it just impact the file extension (i.e. .so versus .dll), the compiler used and possibly the way symbols are exported (Windows requires some minor changes compared to Linux/MacOS).

Fast C implementation
Here is a fast implementation written in C:
// compute.c

// Naive implementation which is neither the fastest nor the most accurate
inline long double naive_sum(const long double* arr, int size)
{
    long double s = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        s += arr[i];

    return s;
}

// This function is slightly faster and a bit more accurate than the naive sum
long double better_sum(const long double* arr, int size)
{
    long double s = 0.0;
    int i;

    // Assume the compiler inline the function calls for sake of performance
    for (i = 0; i+15 < size; i += 16)
        s += naive_sum(&arr[i], 16);

    s += naive_sum(&arr[i], size-i);
    return s;
}

You can compile the code easily with the following command:
# Note for Windows: use ".dll" instead of ".so"
# Note that `-ffast-math` and `-march=native` should give no/minor performance benefit on x86 CPUs
gcc -O3 --shared -o libcompute.so compute.c


Calling the C functions from Python
There are several ways to call C functions from Python. One way is to use the standard ctypes (built-in) Python module. It tends to be relatively fast.
Here is an example:
import ctypes
import numpy as np

# Load the library
lib = ctypes.CDLL('./libcompute.so')

# Define the function
lib.better_sum.argtypes = [np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float128, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS'), ctypes.c_int]
lib.better_sum.restype = ctypes.c_longdouble
better_sum = lib.better_sum

A = np.random.random(1000).astype(dtype=np.float128)
%timeit better_sum(A, A.size)

On my machine (AMD 5700U) with CPython 3.10.12 and Numpy 1.26.4, it takes 3.86 µs while np.sum(A) takes 3.73 µs and A.sum() takes 2.76 µs. Not so bad, but not optimal!
It turns out that most of the time of the above code is spent in ctypes and Numpy: ctypes needs to extract the pointer of the Numpy array, do some checks, convert objects to native types, do the actual call and convert the result back to a Python object. All of this seems to take about 2.8 µs!

Faster way to call the C functions
Since the function to be executed last for only few microsecond, there is no time for caution! We cannot afford the time to do checks using a slow interpreted code. As a result, there are two possible options :

move the all the checks in a compiled C code which directly operate on the Numpy array internal data structure (require to write a low-level C code using C extension).
not to do any check and assume the caller do the right things and exactly know what it does (otherwise it can just crash or corrupt the interpreter).

Since the former solution is tedious, let's try the later one.
We can extract the Numpy array information (pointer and size) ahead of time and then call the C function. This solution assume the array is contiguous in memory (i.e. its stride is 1) and the type of the item (np.float128) matches with the C type long double. Here is the resulting code:
import ctypes
import numpy as np

lib = ctypes.CDLL('./libcompute.so')

lib.better_sum.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_int]
lib.better_sum.restype = ctypes.c_longdouble
better_sum = lib.better_sum

A = np.random.random(1000).astype(dtype=np.float128)
A_ptr = ctypes.c_void_p(A.ctypes.data)
A_size = ctypes.c_int(A.size)

%timeit better_sum(A_ptr, A_size)

Now the function takes 1.19 µs on my machine which seems very good and faster than the best Numpy implementation.
The overhead of calling the function is now about 260 ns and I think this is close to be optimal. Indeed, one should remember we are calling a C function from a Python interpreter, better_sum, A_ptr and A_size are 3 dynamic reference-counted Python objects and the output still needs to be converted back to a Python objects created on the fly. In fact, Numba barely does a better job by generating the wrapping function (converting objects to native types, doing type checks, etc.) at runtime and compiling it (which is AFAIK nearly optimal for many runs). If you want something faster, then you certainly need to convert the code of the caller function in a native language (like C/C++) too so not to pay the overhead of CPython/ctypes. Indeed, calling a function in C is much faster (>30 times on my machine). At this granularity, CPython is a bottleneck.
The overhead of extracting the Numpy array information is about 1.1 µs which is not great but it seems Numpy is actually the main bottleneck here. It is only a problem if you operate on different/new arrays which is inefficient anyway. If you perform in-place operation, this is not a problem since the pointer remains the same.
Note that the output is converted back to a float Python type which is generally 64-bit while the function output is a long double. This means some digits are lost using this implicit ctypes conversion. One way to avoid this is to use pointers or to store the output in a Numpy array of size 1.

Summary of the performance results
np.sum(A):                   3.73 µs
A.sum():                     2.76 µs
Basic ctypes calls:          3.86 µs
Optimized ctypes calls:      1.19 µs *     <----------
Actual C computation time:  ~0.93 µs

* Do not include the time to extract Numpy array information


Notes
Note that C functions can also be called from Numba (possibly using ctypes too).
However, one should note that Numba does not support by default Numpy array with np.float128 items anyway. If needed, one can overpass this limit using A.view(np.uint8) though it is not great since it break the type system (including checks) so I do not recommend this.

I look forward to trying this! Would cffi be an option with lower overhead than ctyoes? I know pypy devs are keen on it.

I first tried CFFI but quick tests show it was a bit more expensive on my machine (using CPython) -- though not much slower still -- and CFFI is a bit less standard than ctypes on CPython (since it is apparently not installed by default), so I finally used ctypes. Besides speed, I think both are fine. Note that performance results can be very different on PyPy.

Is there no way to return a np.float128 without having to cast back to a 64 bit type?

I found no way in the documentation so far. They states that return value are transparently converted and we never get ctype object but native Python types instead. The only solution I am aware of is stated in the answer : "One way to avoid this is to use pointers or to store the output in a Numpy array of size 1". Pointers are certainly the way to go since you can easily create a c_longdouble object and then extract its address with byref so to give it to the C function in parameter (which needs to be of type long double*) and the C function should then return nothing (i.e. void).

If you want to do Numpy/Python manipulations on the result (i.e. not C ones), then creating a Numpy array of size 1 is more flexible, so the best solution is dependent of what you plan to do with the result. By the way, note that returning value based on pointers in parameter is very common in C (especially for large structures since it is actually more efficient).

I would be happy with an array of size 1 as the output

BF16 is a supported type in LLVM, although with some restrictions. That's why a+b is implemented as one * a + b - for BF16 LLVM implements only Fused Multiply and Add (FMA), which is abused here with a constant 1.
You need to implement your FP128 add in LLVM here instead. That means extracting the 80 value bits out of the 128 bits, use them as x86_fp80 values, add those, add back the 48 bits of padding, and return that. No need for FMA hacks.

Thank you . I am really hoping for an answer spelling out how to do that.

Are you sure that you need to have a numba for this? Can't numpy handle this tasks by itself?
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random(size=[100])
a = a.astype(np.longdouble)
a = a * 1e-75

t = a[np.newaxis,:].sum(axis=-1)
str(t[0])


I am trying to speed up the summation.  numba is much faster when the type  is np.float64 and I am assuming that a similar speedup will be possible for np.float128 if I can work out how to get numba to support that type.

JIT will speed maybe 10-20% compared with numpy. Numpy already works quite well. Here are the benchmarks Sum: pure numpy float64 0.0087 --
Sum: jit floa64 0.0059 -- Sum: pure numpy float128 0.0243

https://bpa.st/AWAQ  It's realy a lost faster, especially if you use fastmath=True. 404 ns for numba, 2.86 µs  for np.sum. That is 7 times faster.

dnk could you pls check with larger array size, for example 10000000

The timings get closer as the array gets longer and end up similar by length 1,000,000.  I am only interested in arrays shorter than that though. https://bpa.st/USGQ  357 µs for numba and 432 µs for np.sum when A.size=1000000

For large arrays, codes are generally memory-bound. This is why they should be close each other performance-wise. Moreover, this is also why I do not have optimized the np.sum implementation of Numpy so far. Indeed, people tends to use Numpy for relatively large arrays and the overhead of calling Numpy functions is quite big on small array (especially for np.sum IMHO). Besides, the current implementation of np.sum also benefit from being more numerically stable. The naive sum of Numba is not as numerically stable as Numpy (but it is rather OK on very-small arrays).

To give more details : the current implementation uses a pair-wise summation which does not use SIMD instructions. Numba is faster in this case because it can use SIMD instruction (the Numpy function call overhead on 1M items is relatively small). The thing is FP80 cannot be accelerated by SIMD units since they only support FP32 and FP64 on x86 CPUs (possibly FP16 on some recent x86-64 CPUs). This is a critical since without that Numba is certainly not much faster.

To make a fair comparison able to predict the performance on FP80, you need to disable the use of SIMD units. fastmath is what causes Numba to use SIMD units instead of scalar computations. So you should not enable fastmath if you want to see whether Numba will help on FP80. Besides, AFAIK FP80 operations are significantly slower than FP64 because they are obsolete nowadays (not standard and much supported anymore except in C, so CPU vendors do not care about its performance). Not to mention FP80 put more pressure on memory. Thus, the Numpy overhead will probably be smaller than on FP64.

I was curious about results myself so I did a test in C++ using Clang+GCC (with optimizations -O3 -march=native -ffast-math) on an array with 1_000_000 and results are very clear on my machine : Numpy is as fast as the C++ code. In fact, the C code is just a bit slightly slower (maybe because of prefetching instructions in the Numpy that compilers do not generate). Here is the C++ code. Results are about the same in -O2 and -O3 as well as for both GCC and Clang (same with/wo -ffast-math which make sense here too).

TL;DR: if you do this operation on Numba on relatively large array (>50K), then it will be equally fast as Numpy. It only worth it for array with <10K items (due to the Numpy function call overhead). PS: maybe I should have written an answer...

@JérômeRichard : should I write up an answer summarizing your comments?

@JérômeRichard I will be working with arrays of length less than 10K.

@Claudio It is not needed since the OP operate on small arrays and also since the question has been updated to add related information.
